# how can I click a button by another button without displaying it?

Tags: java, android, button

I want to send the data of a button1 by clicking another button2 is that possible in android, without showing button1 to the user?

Comment: How about creating a reusable method?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically "click" a button by calling its `callOnClick` method.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick()) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either using [View.performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) or [View.callOnClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick()).

But you should revisit your code. Is the code inside the buttons can be refactored to methods? Is the code can be reused can recall in another button?

What you're code now probably something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do process when button A clicked.
        } 
    });

    buttonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do process when button B clicked.
        } 
    });

    ...

}
```

You can refactor the inside of each of your buttons to methods, something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do process when button A clicked.
            processButtonA();
        } 
    });

    buttonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do process when button B clicked.
            processButtonB();
        } 
    });

    ...
}

private void processButtonA() {
  // something here.
}

private void processButtonB() {
  // something here.
}
```

then, if you need to call process related with the button B from button A, you can do the following:

```
buttonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        processButtonA();
        processButtonB();
    } 
});
```

Comment: thanks, dear, but my code for buttonB is something like this:    
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   IrData.put(R.id.buttonb, hextodec("0000 006d 0026 0000 0155 00aa 0016 0015 0016 0015 0016 0040 0016 0015 0016 0015 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0015 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0015 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 00400e58 0155 0055 0016 00aa 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0014 0016 "));

Comment: then inside buttonA I am recording a command, if the command is the same as my database commands I wand to send the data of buttonB